# Docker machine in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, docker

Should I run `docker-machine stop default` every time before I shutdown my Mac? Or is it ok to shutdown with the machine 'running'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (mostly) ok to shutdown your system with "running" *machines*.

For local *machines* you will be relying on your VM's normal shutdown behaviour at system shutdown. For externally hosted *machines*, they will be left running.

With `docker-machine` on OSX and VirtualBox 5.x, any *machines* running on VirtualBox VM's will be paused and have their current state saved when the host is shutdown. The *machine* will be left in this state at system startup until you start them back up (via `docker-machine` or some VirtualBox method)

`docker-machine` does not attempt to do anything to your *machines* on a shutdown signal as it is not a system daemon. `docker-machine` is a cli utility you manually run to manage machines.

The "mostly" caveat is that some applications really struggle with the time dilation that occurs from pausing a VM. If you do run into issues with your os or apps you could have [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) manage the [vm completely so it starts and stops automatically](https://www.petekeen.net/start-virtualbox-vm-at-boot-os-x) when you login. There is most likely a plist to make launchd run a `docker-machine stop default` at logoff too.

Answer (score 1):

Docker will receive the shutdown signal and try to shut itself down. It however does not guarantee a graceful shutdown for all of the containers; and it might prevent your mac from shutting down in the process.

**Edit**

[From their source code](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/stop.go)

> > // containerStop halts a container by sending a stop signal, waiting for the given
> >
> > // duration in seconds, and then calling SIGKILL and waiting for the
> >
> > // process to exit. If a negative duration is given, Stop will wait
> >
> > // for the initial signal forever. If the container is not running Stop returns immediately.

I have not found any mention that containers will be paused and committed

Comment: Good to know. Thks. = )

Comment: So does `docker-machine` attempt to shutdown virtual machines? What about external machines? I'm pretty sure in the VirtualBox case, VirtualBox itself on shutdown will pause the local vms and save their state, rather than shutting down completely.

Comment: @Matt: I updated my answer. It attempts to ask them to stop. But will yank the plug if they don't in a given time

Comment: That's the code for the `docker` daemon itself stopping running containers. On a mac there is no local `docker` daemon, `docker-machine` is a cli utility to manage _machines_ that run the docker daemon. By default this is a local virtualbox vm but it can also manage remote machines. Docker would only receive a shutdown signal and stop containers if the vm/machine received some sort of signal.